# Regular Expression Validator - number, letters and a dash and space?

Tags: regex

I have a `RegularExpressionValidator` that I'm trying to validate for all characters (upper and lower), numbers, spaces and a dash.

I have this right now:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator
    ID="RegularExpressionValidator1"
    runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="txtCase"
    ValidationExpression="^[A-Z0-9 _]*$" 
    ForeColor= "Red"
    ErrorMessage="No Special Characters allowed">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Right now it only works for lower case letter and number combination.

How can I add upper case letters and a dash to it?

Comment: Does something like `[0-9a-zA-Z\s\-_]+` work?

Comment: yes! thank you! if you post it i'll mark it as answer :)

Comment: @summea. Why did you remove your perfectly good answer?

Comment: @MikeM stema made a better point with the Unicode aspect; I was thinking in more-archaic expressions...

Comment: @summea. The OP probably only wanted `A-Za-z` anyway.

Comment: @MikeM probably true; but for what it's worth, it's not a bad idea to think ahead... even if the OP never ends up using Unicode in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want **all** letters, you need to use Unicode code properties:

```
ValidationExpression="[\p{L}\d -]+"
```

`\p{L}` is a [Unicode code property](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html), matching all letters in every language

`\d` [is a digit](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) (also Unicode based)

Comment: Yes, that was me. Apologies, it was locked-in before I found out that anchoring is assumed and therefore unnecessary. I owe you one.

Comment: @MikeM, no problem, I had also to search here on SO before my answer to find out if anchors are needed or not. Btw. I edited my answer, that removed the lock, you are welcome to remove your downvote.